# How do I set up this while loop properly?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium

I'm creating a function in an app of mine, that will check if a Zoom meeting is present by reloading the page every 5 seconds if it isn't. I'm using Selenium in Python 3.

Here's what I've done right now:

```
def CheckZoomMeeting():

    # Attempts to locate the Zoom meeting.
    try:
        element_present = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[1]/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/div/div/div/div[1]/div[2]')   # ADD THE JOIN MEETING XPATH HERE

    # If the element does not exist, it is False.
    except NoSuchElementException:
        element_present = False

    # This is a loop that will keep reloading the page every 5 seconds, until element_present does not equal False.
    while element_present == False:
        time.sleep(5)
        driver.refresh()

    # Once it equals something other than False (meaning the Zoom meeting is there), it will just continue on.
    else:
        pass
```

And while I can't actually test this right now (because no Zoom meetings are actually being set up at the moment), it's my understanding that this will just keep reloading forever, as the result is *stored* inside `element_present`.

So what I want to do is create a loop that reloads the page every 5 seconds if the element isn't there by checking whether it is or not every time, and then `else: pass #and continue with the rest of the code`

This would be easy if `element_present = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[1]/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/div/div/div/div[1]/div[2]')` returned a `True` or `False` variable, but, by default, it doesn't. What can I do to make this loop actually work?

It's probably a simple solution that I should've thought of, but it just isn't coming to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the variable to `None` then loop until the variable is set to a value.

```
def CheckZoomMeeting():

    element_present = None

    # Attempts to locate the Zoom meeting.
    while not element_present:  # until element found
        try:
            element_present = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[1]/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/div/div/div/div[1]/div[2]')   # ADD THE JOIN MEETING XPATH HERE

        # If the element does not exist, it is False.
        except NoSuchElementException:
            element_present = False

        # This is a loop that will keep reloading the page every 5 seconds, until element_present does not equal False.
        if not element_present:
            time.sleep(5)
            driver.refresh()

    # Once it equals something other than False (meaning the Zoom meeting is there), it will just continue on.
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Thank you, I'll know this for next time!